# Пытаюсь получить ответ из бд в виде json'а

Tags: php, mysql, json

mysql_fetch_assoc() просит какой-то параметр в виде ресурса, не понимаю что э то значит, основной код:

```js
<?php
$data = array(); // в этот массив запишем то, что выберем из базы
require_once 'conf.php'; /* Connect */
$ta ="SELECT * FROM Groups"; /* Query */
$result = mysqli_query($link, $ta) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); /* Go query */
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ta)){ // оформим каждую строку результата
                                      // как ассоциативный массив
    $data[] = $row; // допишем строку из выборки как новый элемент результирующего массива
}
echo json_encode($data);
 mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Код конфига:

```js
<?php
/* Connect DB */
$link = mysqli_connect(
            '', /* host */
            '', /* user */
            '', /* pass */
            ''); /* db */
$table = "Groups"; /* table */

/* If connect = false */
if (!$link) {
   printf("Невозможно подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); /* print error */
   exit; /* close */
}
?>
```

Ошибка: **Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource**
Собственно, почему возникает эта ошибка и что она означает ну и по классике, как решить)

Comment: Допишите в вопросе сому ошибку.

Comment: @RazGalstyan, сому писать не нужно. Сом - рыба, он не поймёт

Comment: @RazGalstyan добавил

Comment: `mysqli_query()`, `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. Вас не смущает, что это функции разных библиотек?

Comment: @ArchDemon в php я не бум бум только учусь, если говорить о mysqli, то какая альтернатива mysql_fetch_assoc()?

Comment: Ну так может стоит сначала почитать книги, статьи, документацию. Стать бум-бум, а потом уже задавать интересные вопросы на SO? Как минимум название функции должно начинаться с `mysqli`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476162/can-i-blindly-replace-all-mysql-functions-with-mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто надо поменять:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($ta)
```

на

```
 mysqli_fetch_array($ta)
```

mysqli это улучшеная, новая версия библиотеки mysql. Так, что если пользоваться  mysqli, то всюду надо писать mysqli.

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите на русском языке.